# Is this clang version install correct on my mac?

Tags: c++, terminal, clang

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CucuN.png)I'm new to programming and I'm learning c++. On my mac, I initially used Xcode to run c++. I followed the setup instructions and had it running. Now, I've moved to VScode as I find it more simpler. In an installation video, I was told to check if clang was installed. In my terminal it displays this for the installed drive. Everybody elses shows "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin"
[Here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CucuN.png)

Is there any issue with mine if I'm going to use VScode on my mac or will any issues pop up in the future because of this? Also some peoples also shows "Apple LLVM version" mine just shows "Apple clang version". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, if you want to check if clang is already installed on your Mac, you can type in "clang --version" in your terminal and show you some basic information about the clang version that is on the Mac. Also there isn't anything wrong with the file path stated! About the Apple LLVM and Apple Clang, there shouldn't be an issue.
Hope this helped!

Comment: thanks for the response. in my image you can see that my terminal shows under installed dir "xcode/applications.../toolchains" instead of "library/developer/commandlinetools/usr/bin" like every other tutorial i've seen. my question was is this correct and will it cause any errors using other interpreters instead of xcode?